# Latex reference sheet for usage with Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, latex

Anyone knows where one could find a Latex reference sheet for usage in Word 2007? I'm interested in some which mostly deals with writing math. Formulas, text formatting and page layout are of lesser importance.

Answer (score 4):

You either use Word or you use LaTeX. You can't do both at the same time.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Equation_Editor

Comment: The Microsoft Equation Editor is not LaTeX. It has some similarities of syntax, but it would be no use having a LaTeX reference sheet as there are too many differences. What you want is a MS-Word equation editor reference sheet.

Comment: ... okey, fair enough ... I did specify "for usage with word'07" ... so that should've given something away ...

Comment: ... in any case, every formula that I had so far in a latex document worked without question ...

Comment: You can edit Latex source in Word.  In fact, that can be a very useful thing to do sometimes; I've worked this way with some clients.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using MS Office, you can't access LaTeX. It's like driving bus and car in one time...

As you commented Rob's post, Word 2007

> For Microsoft Office 2007, Equation Editor is included as is, however some Office 2007 applications also include a reengineered equation editor with support for a TeX-like linear input/edit language called "Office Math Markup Language" (Office MathML or OMML) in addition to its WYSIWYG interface.

For me that means, that programmers of MS created GUI for using TeX for typesetting math. So that TeX is used only in box with math text, rest of the document is created by Word.

Comment: Tex-like means they’re actually not using Tex but something which is, well, Tex-like.

Comment: @Crowley - ... I thought I mentioned exactly that in my question ...